# Is it possible to load a Netty Socket Server on Jboss AS 7 startup?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netty, jboss7.x, serversocket

We have a "standalone" Socket Server in java that accepts many requests (xml string) from clients around our network. That is working just great. The problem is that now in the server side we need to consume some WebServices published in a different server.

As i understand, we need to be standing on a WebServer to consume those web services (right?), so we install JBOSS AS 7.1 and generate the client and now we are able to consume those web services..

The question is: how can we mix both parts? i mean Recieve the request in a socket, then call the web service using the information received and then respond to the socket client whatever the webservice result was...

I had the idea to implement Netty to start the Socket server at JBOSS startup and just call the webservice on the handlers but im lost.. any advice on how can i configure Jboss to startup the Socket server? I also was taking a look at JBOSS Remoting but since im using JBOSS AS 7 couldn't find any documentation for Remoting 3....

Answer (score 1):

No, to my knowledge consuming WebServices should be possible outside of a Java EE container as well. You just have to make sure you include all dependencies.

Your "standalone" socket server, does it use HTTP or just TCP?

If you want to integrate with JBoss the easiest would probably be to write a SAR. What's more work but gives you better integration is to write a custom [subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Extending+JBoss+AS+7). This also allows you to hook into the JBoss configuration.

JBoss remoting is mostly used for things like EJB calls.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the SocketServer is just TCP.. actually the integration of JBOSS was just to be able to call Web Services in a "native" way, because we used to simulate a call using something like curl but we are trying to migrate everything to java. We are on a HP-UNIX Itanium.

Comment: JAX-WS is certainly the standard way to use web services in Java. However, it's geared towards SOAP. It [isn't well-suited to REST](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2006/08/jax-ws-for-restful-web-services) (ie "plain XML over HTTP"). If your server uses SOAP, then use JAX-WS, but if it's REST or XML over TCP, then you are better off just using a simple HTTP client (URLConnection or Apache HttpComponents) and parsing the XML (with a DOM parser, or JAXB, or XStream, or whatever). Happily, both JAX-WS and the HTTP+XML approach are entirely usable outside a Java EE container. You don't need JBoss here.